# Scroll to top of page in React-Native

Tags: list, react-native, scrolltop

In the native page, if i touch any of the item in second list(after `Header`) i have to show the top(first list -in top) of the page. I have tried `this.refs.listRef.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})`, but it didn't solve my problem

```
<Content>
          <ScrollView ref="listRef">
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'#e0e0e0'}}>
              {InvoiceStore.invoice_response2==2?<View>
              {InvoiceStore.invoice.length>0?
                <View style={{width:deviceWidth-(deviceWidth/50),
            padding:deviceWidth/70,alignSelf:'center',backgroundColor:'white',elevation:5,marginTop:deviceHeight/60,marginBottom:deviceHeight/60}}>
                  <List dataArray={InvoiceStore.invoice.slice()}
                    renderRow={(data) =>((data.length!=0)?<ListItem>................................................................................................................................................................... </ListItem>
                    :<View></View>)}>
                  </List>
                </View>
              :<View></View>}
              </View>:<Spinner/>}
            </View>



<Header style={{backgroundColor:'#d0964b',height:30}}>.......</Header>
{InvoiceStore.invoice_response2==2?<View>
              {InvoiceStore.invoice.length>0?
                <View style={{width:deviceWidth-(deviceWidth/50),
            padding:deviceWidth/70,alignSelf:'center',backgroundColor:'white',elevation:5,marginTop:deviceHeight/60,marginBottom:deviceHeight/60}}>
                  <List dataArray={InvoiceStore.invoice.slice()}
                    renderRow={(data) =>((data.length!=0)?<ListItem>................................................................................................................................................................... </ListItem>
                    :<View></View>)}>
                  </List>
                </View>
              :<View></View>}
              </View>:<Spinner/>}

</ScrollView>
```

In the secon list i have scrolled to the bottom , the above list and Headers are hidden from display.  If i click any of the item in the second list that data are visible in the page start (first list ) , for that I have scroll the screen to top on Item click.

is there any other way....

Comment: I have tried """"this.refs.listRef.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})"""""" _________   with_____""""""""""<ScrollView ref="listRef">""""""""</ScrollView> , not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just worked after removing `Container`, `Content` components